# Flip Horizontal Segue between view controllers but in opposite direction (compared to default)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm using Xcode 12, and I want to make the flip horizontal transition in the opposite direction. Right now, it goes from right to left, but I want to make it go from left to right. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To reverse the direction of a `UIViewAnimationOptions` transition, you can use the `.reverse` modifier:

```swift
let transitionOptions: UIView.AnimationOptions = [.transitionFlipFromRight, .reverse]
```

Comment: When I paste that into my code, I get an error: "UIView.AnimationOptions.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'UIView.AnimationOptions') has no member 'reverse'".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).